# how to let filesystem::path's c_str() work?

Tags: c++, string, char, filesystems, wchar-t

I have a question:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <filesystem>
int main()
{
    using namespace std;
    using namespace filesystem;
    path p = current_path();
    cout << p << endl;
    cout << p.string() << endl;
    cout << p.string().c_str() << endl;
    cout << p.c_str() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The output is here:

```
"D:\\VSCodeData\\EffectiveC++"
D:\VSCodeData\EffectiveC++
D:\VSCodeData\EffectiveC++
0x1667248
```

I don't know why the fourth doesn't work.

The other question is here:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <filesystem>
int main()
{
    using namespace std;
    using namespace filesystem;
    path p = current_path();

    auto sptr = p.string().c_str();

    cout << "this is OK: " << p.string().c_str() << endl;
    cout << "After operator=  : " << sptr << endl;
    cout << "convert to const char* :" << (const char *)p.c_str() << endl;
}
```

The output is here:

```
this is OK: D:\VSCodeData\EffectiveC++
After operator=  :
convert to const char* :D
```

I don't know what happend.

Comment: because it's wchar_t, not char

Comment: `p.c_str()` on Windows returns a `wchar_t const*`.  You'll need to convert the wchar_t string into a char string to `cout <<` it.

Comment: ... or write it the wide character console: `wcout << p.c_str() << endl;`

Answer (score 1):

On Windows `path::c_str()` returns `wchar_t const*` and not `char const*`. You can use `wcout` to print it:

```
wcout << p.c_str() << '\n';
```

Comment: yeah, I understand it finally, thanks!!

Comment: @user18894745 Glad I could help. If you want this to be platform-independent, you might add a function called `print` that is overloaded to take `string` or `wstring` and print.

Answer (score 1):

p.string() return a string value,

what is the lifetime of this value ?

```
auto sptr = p.string().c_str(); // the value returned by p.string() is destructed after this line
```

so sptr is a dangling pointer because it refer to a destructed string

Comment: yeah at last I understand it, thank you!!